# How can I convert an array to an object in the $group stage of an aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a group stage in a mongodb aggregation pipeline that looks like this:

```
$group: {
    _id: null,
    comments: {
        $push: {
            _id: "$comments._id", 
            comment: "$comments.comment",
            creator: "$comments.creator"
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": null,
    comments: [{
        "_id": "5c113250b54e8a5bc4412a9a",
        "comment": "This is my comment",
        "creator": [{
            "_id": "5c113250b54e8a5bb9252a7b",
            "name": "John Doe"
        }, ...]
    }]
}
```

Notice that `creator` is an array. I want it to just be an object. For some reason this isn't easy to do (it probably is, but I can't figure it out). Here is what I've tried:

```
$group: {
    _id: null,
    comments: {
        $push: {
            _id: "$comments._id", 
            comment: "$comments.comment",
            creator: {$arrayToObject: "$comments.creator"}
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I convert the `creator` array to an object?

Comment: why is that an array? you can do $first in case if you don't need remaining

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
creator: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$comments.creator", 0 ] }
```